# Call method or class using generics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a doubt about how generics are implemented and I hope you can support or guide me to implement it in my case.

Well, I'm working on a playlist of files or a gallery and this will be able to play various types of file formats (mp3, jpg, mp4, obj, ect) then I want to avoid modifying my code for each type of method that is responsible for importing these types of files. I have been reading about generics and I see that it solves my problem but I don't know how to implement it.

Could you help me with this? or is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

That's all. Thank you very much!

This is my code made in Unity:

Script 1:

```
    public class GalleryItem : MonoBehaviour
```

{
#region VARIABLES

```
[SerializeField]
private GalleryContextMenu contextMenu;

[Header("Settings")]

[SerializeField]
internal Color normalItemColor = Color.white;

[SerializeField]
internal Color hoveredItemColor = new Color32(225, 225, 255, 255);

[SerializeField]
internal Color selectedItemColor = new Color32(0, 175, 255, 255);

[Serializable]
private struct FiletypeIcon
{
    public string extension;
    public Sprite icon;
}

[Header("Icons")]

[SerializeField]
private FiletypeIcon[] filetypeIcons;

//Listas
private readonly List<int> selectedFileEntries = new List<int>(4);

private readonly List<FileItem> allItems = new List<FileItem>(16);

private readonly List<WidgetItem> allWidgetItems = new List<WidgetItem>();

private List<GameObject> buttonFileList = new List<GameObject>();

internal List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();

//Indice para cada item
internal int sharedValue;

internal string fullFilePath;

//Cantidad de items
private int items;

[Header("Canvas")]

//Contenedor de items
public RectTransform content;

//Item a instanciar
public GameObject itemPrefab;

//Canvas que contiene la galeria de items
public Canvas canvas;
public RectTransform rectTransform;

#endregion

#region MÉTODOS DE INICIALIZACIÓN

private void Awake()
{
    items = 0;
}

private void InitializeDataItem()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < filetypeIcons.Length; j++)
    {
        if (fullFilePath.Contains(filetypeIcons[j].extension))
            allItems[items].SetFile(filetypeIcons[j].icon, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFilePath));
    }
}

#endregion

#region MÉTODOS PARA ABRIR EL EXPLORADOR DE ARCHIVOS

public void StartFileBrowser()
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowLoadingCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator ShowLoadingCoroutine()
{
    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(FileBrowser.PickMode.FilesAndFolders, true, null, null, "Abrir archivos y carpetas", "Cargar");

    if (FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        fullFilePath = FileBrowser.Result[0].ToLowerInvariant();
        OnCreateItem("item", itemPrefab, content);
        OnCreateWidgetItem("WidgetButton");
    }
}

#endregion

#region MÉTODO PARA AGREGAR Y ELEIMINAR ELEMENTOS DE LA GALERÍA
public void DeleteItem()
{
    Destroy(buttonFileList[sharedValue]);
    Destroy(allItems[sharedValue]);

    buttonFileList.RemoveAt(sharedValue);
    allItems.RemoveAt(sharedValue);
    allWidgetItems.RemoveAt(sharedValue);
    allFiles.RemoveAt(sharedValue);

    items -= 1;
    Refresh();
}

private void Refresh()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonFileList.Count; i++)
        buttonFileList[i].name = "item_" + i;

    for (int i = 0; i < allWidgetItems.Count; i++)
    {
        allWidgetItems[i].gameObject.name = "WidgetButton" + i;
    }

    if (buttonFileList.Count == 0)
        items = 0;
}

private void OnCreateWidgetItem(string name)
{
    WidgetItem widget = GameObject.Find("WidgetButton").GetComponentInChildren<WidgetItem>();
    widget.name = name + "_" + (items - 1);

    allWidgetItems.Add(widget);
}

private void OnCreateItem(string name, GameObject prefab, Transform parent)
{
    FileItem item = (FileItem)Instantiate(prefab.GetComponent<FileItem>(), parent, false);            

    item.name = name + "_" + items;

    buttonFileList.Add(item.gameObject);
    allItems.Add(item);
    allFiles.Add(fullFilePath);

    InitializeDataItem();

    items += 1;
}

#endregion

#region MENÚ CONTEXTUAL

internal void OnContextMenuTriggered()
{
    Vector2 position;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rectTransform, Input.mousePosition, canvas.worldCamera, out position);

    contextMenu.Show(position, false);
}

#endregion

#region HOVER PARA ELEMENTOS

public void OnItemSelected(FileItem item, bool isDobleClick)
{
    if (item == null)
        return;

    if (!isDobleClick)
    {
        selectedFileEntries.Clear();
        selectedFileEntries.Add(item.Position);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (allItems[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
            allItems[i].SetSelected(false);
    }
    item.SetSelected(selectedFileEntries.Contains(item.Position));
}

public void OnSelectedWidgetItem()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allWidgetItems.Count; i++)
    {
        allWidgetItems[i].isPlaying = false;
        allWidgetItems[i].PlayingNull();
    }
}
```

Script 2:

```
 public class GalleryItem : MonoBehaviour
```

{
#region VARIABLES

```
[SerializeField]
private GalleryContextMenu contextMenu;

[Header("Settings")]

[SerializeField]
internal Color normalItemColor = Color.white;

[SerializeField]
internal Color hoveredItemColor = new Color32(225, 225, 255, 255);

[SerializeField]
internal Color selectedItemColor = new Color32(0, 175, 255, 255);

[Serializable]
private struct FiletypeIcon
{
    public string extension;
    public Sprite icon;
}

[Header("Icons")]

[SerializeField]
private FiletypeIcon[] filetypeIcons;

//Listas
private readonly List<int> selectedFileEntries = new List<int>(4);

private readonly List<FileItem> allItems = new List<FileItem>(16);

private readonly List<WidgetItem> allWidgetItems = new List<WidgetItem>();

private List<GameObject> buttonFileList = new List<GameObject>();

internal List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();

//Indice para cada item
internal int sharedValue;

internal string fullFilePath;

//Cantidad de items
private int items;

[Header("Canvas")]

//Contenedor de items
public RectTransform content;

//Item a instanciar
public GameObject itemPrefab;

//Canvas que contiene la galeria de items
public Canvas canvas;
public RectTransform rectTransform;

#endregion

#region MÉTODOS DE INICIALIZACIÓN

private void Awake()
{
    items = 0;
}

private void InitializeDataItem()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < filetypeIcons.Length; j++)
    {
        if (fullFilePath.Contains(filetypeIcons[j].extension))
            allItems[items].SetFile(filetypeIcons[j].icon, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFilePath));
    }
}

#endregion

#region MÉTODOS PARA ABRIR EL EXPLORADOR DE ARCHIVOS

public void StartFileBrowser()
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowLoadingCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator ShowLoadingCoroutine()
{
    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(FileBrowser.PickMode.FilesAndFolders, true, null, null, "Abrir archivos y carpetas", "Cargar");

    if (FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        fullFilePath = FileBrowser.Result[0].ToLowerInvariant();
        OnCreateItem("item", itemPrefab, content);
        OnCreateWidgetItem("WidgetButton");
    }
}

#endregion

#region MÉTODO PARA AGREGAR Y ELEIMINAR ELEMENTOS DE LA GALERÍA
public void DeleteItem()
{
    Destroy(buttonFileList[sharedValue]);
    Destroy(allItems[sharedValue]);

    buttonFileList.RemoveAt(sharedValue);
    allItems.RemoveAt(sharedValue);
    allWidgetItems.RemoveAt(sharedValue);
    allFiles.RemoveAt(sharedValue);

    items -= 1;
    Refresh();
}

private void Refresh()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonFileList.Count; i++)
        buttonFileList[i].name = "item_" + i;

    for (int i = 0; i < allWidgetItems.Count; i++)
    {
        allWidgetItems[i].gameObject.name = "WidgetButton" + i;
    }

    if (buttonFileList.Count == 0)
        items = 0;
}

private void OnCreateWidgetItem(string name)
{
    WidgetItem widget = GameObject.Find("WidgetButton").GetComponentInChildren<WidgetItem>();
    widget.name = name + "_" + (items - 1);

    allWidgetItems.Add(widget);
}

private void OnCreateItem(string name, GameObject prefab, Transform parent)
{
    FileItem item = (FileItem)Instantiate(prefab.GetComponent<FileItem>(), parent, false);            

    item.name = name + "_" + items;

    buttonFileList.Add(item.gameObject);
    allItems.Add(item);
    allFiles.Add(fullFilePath);

    InitializeDataItem();

    items += 1;
}

#endregion

#region MENÚ CONTEXTUAL

internal void OnContextMenuTriggered()
{
    Vector2 position;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rectTransform, Input.mousePosition, canvas.worldCamera, out position);

    contextMenu.Show(position, false);
}

#endregion

#region HOVER PARA ELEMENTOS

public void OnItemSelected(FileItem item, bool isDobleClick)
{
    if (item == null)
        return;

    if (!isDobleClick)
    {
        selectedFileEntries.Clear();
        selectedFileEntries.Add(item.Position);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (allItems[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
            allItems[i].SetSelected(false);
    }
    item.SetSelected(selectedFileEntries.Contains(item.Position));
}

public void OnSelectedWidgetItem()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allWidgetItems.Count; i++)
    {
        allWidgetItems[i].isPlaying = false;
        allWidgetItems[i].PlayingNull();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this isn't a question about using the Visual Studio application. Please ensure you read tag descriptions and that you only add relevant tags to your question.

Comment: Just a general "clean code" advice: The comment `Listas` is not really necessary .. one can already see that the type of the fields is `List<T>` ;) And comments like `/*Indice para cada item*/ internal int sharedValue;` or `/*Cantidad de items*/ private int items;` can be avoided by more precise naming like e.g. `internal int sharedItemIndex;` or `private int amountOfItems;` ;) In general make all these comments proper XML ones using e.g. `/// <summary>Description here</summary>` this way any decent IDE will display that description when hovering the type/name anywhere in the code

Comment: And .. actually where exactly is the difference between Script1 and Script 2 ? They are so large I didn't go through it all but I didn't see any difference on first glance ...

Comment: @deHugo Hi, 

thank you very much for the advice, I will take it into account because I am just starting to program using good practices.
Script 1 and 2 are what I have already done.
 My idea is to create a script that takes care of accepting various file formats without the need for me to program or modify my previous scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are useful in a situation where you want a way of taking some description of an operation and applying it to a bunch of different types.  For instance, you might want to make a container that can hold different types of objects.

In the case of a playlist that's not really what you're doing, because you're thinking about a list of objects of differing types.  What you want instead is a base type or interface that provides the functionality you need, like so:

```
interface IPlayable
{
  void play();
  void stop();
  void rewind();
  // ...
}

class MP3File : IPlayable
{
  public void play() { /* ... */ } 
  // ...
}

class MP3File : IPlayable
{
  public void play() { /* ... */ } 
  // ...
}

class WAVFile : IPlayable
{
  public void play() { /* ... */ } 
  // ...  
}
```

and then you could declare your playlist as

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<IPlayable> myPlaylist;
```

and do things like

```
myPlaylist.add(new MP3File("song.mp3"));

myPlaylist[i].play();
```

You mentioned wanting to load things.  For that what you probably want is a factory method, like so

```
IPlayable makePlayable(string filename)
{
  switch(Path.getExtension(filename))
  {
    case ".mp3" : return new MP3File(filename);
    case ".wav" : return new WaveFile(filename);
    // ...
    default: return null;  // or throw, or ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I pretty much doubt it will make any difference **at all** .. innUnity all audio files are treated as [`AudioClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html) which is what e.g. [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) replays. OP rather has a very different set of items with different use cases: Audio, Video, Image, 3DModel, etc .. so they all need to be treated differently and have different functionality when it comes to "what to do with this item" ;)

Comment: E.g. audio and video can be opened, started, paused .. while an image can only be opened or closed ... a 3D model can be loaded and destroyed .. etc

Comment: @deHugo I was afraid of that, so it is not possible? What I wanted to avoid is to modify my code when I want to add a new file format, that's why I was reading about methods and generic classes. :(